# Decoding JSON Bool... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: json, swift, decoding

I'm not sure why one variable is not getting parsed correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

Other variables of *String* or *[String]* and even others are working fine.

The part in the JSON file where things seem to go wrong is:

"isRequired": true

The JSON parsing looks like this:

```
guard let FoodPrepJSON = PrepDB.parse(jsonFile: "foodPrepsDB") else { 
        fatalError("FoodPrepJSON URL cannot be found, or file cannot be parsed")
    }
```

Below is the relevant struct. Since I had to decode into different subclasses, I used 'init' and 'switch'. The code breaks near the bottom.

```
struct PrepSection : Decodable {
    var label : String
    var key : String
    var isRequired : Bool?           // This is the Problem Variable
    var searchKeywords : [String]?
    var prepItems : [PrepItem]
    
    
    enum PrepItemKey : CodingKey {  // DrinksKey
        case label
        case key
        case isRequired
        case searchKeywords
        case prepItems
    }
    
    enum PrepItemTypesKey : CodingKey { // Drink Prepare TypeKey
        case type
    }
    
    // Set the types of prep items here
    enum PrepItemTypes: String, Decodable {     //DrinkTypes
        case water = "water"
        case beer = "beer"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PrepItemKey.self)
        
        // init prep items:
        var prepItemsArrayForType = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: PrepItemKey.prepItems)
        var prepItems = [PrepItem]()
        
        var itemsArray = prepItemsArrayForType
        
        // decode prep item and associate it with a sub-Class type
        while(!prepItemsArrayForType.isAtEnd){
            let item = try prepItemsArrayForType.nestedContainer(keyedBy: PrepItemTypesKey.self)
            let type = try item.decode(PrepItemTypes.self, forKey: PrepItemTypesKey.type)
            
            switch type {
            case .water:
                prepItems.append(try itemsArray.decode(Water.self))
            case .beer:
                prepItems.append(try itemsArray.decode(Beer.self))
            }
            
            
        }
        
        self.prepItems = prepItems
        
        
        // init label
        self.label = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .label)
        
        // init key
        self.key = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .key)
        
        

        // THIS IS THE LINE AT WHICH MY CODE BREAKS, If I exclude this line then all variables get decoded fine
        self.isRequired = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isRequired)   



        // init keywords
        self.searchKeywords = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .searchKeywords)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a custom init at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `decode` to a `Bool` to `decodeIfPresent` to a `Bool?`.

Comment: Thank you!... I'm still new to Swift and didn't know that the "If Present" was an option... but that saved the day. Apparently in one of the many JSON lines, indeed the "isRequired" was not present.  THANK YOU for your help and lightning-fast response.